# How to schedule a period of time in which power-on or log-in is prevented?

Tags: boot, power-management, init-script, access-control

So you may get a better idea of the context, this idea comes from the specific problematic of "letting kids being progressively responsible of their own devices".

So I was wondering if there is any possibility to prevent power-on in specific periods of time in order to keep computer usage in the negative ones (an example would be to allow connection only between 5 and 6:30 PM).

And if not, then to prevent log-in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your operating system can’t prevent power-*on*; that would be controlled by the system firmware (but I’ve never seen anything like that).

You can force the system to power *off* if it’s switched on though, *e.g.* with a cronjob like

```
* 0-16 * * * /sbin/poweroff
```

to power the system down if it’s on at any time between midnight and 17:00 (excluded) — this runs `poweroff` every minute between midnight and 16:59. Be careful with this one since the system will shut down even if it’s being used.

You can also use [`/etc/nologin`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nologin.5.html) to prevent logins; again, a cronjob can set this up:

```
* 0-16,19-23 * * * touch /etc/nologin
* 17-18 * * * rm -f /etc/nologin
```

would prevent new logins outside 17:00-18:59. This won’t affect currently-logged-in users though, which might defeat the purpose in your scenario.

Comment: Okay, that worked quite nicely, thank you very much :-)